# android textureview onsurfacetexturedestroyed not called

Tags: android, textureview

I have demo apllication from android [manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html)
Its working good with my nexus 4 but wont with Samsung SIII.
When application goes to onStop on Nexus I got onsurfacetexturedestroyed.
When application goes to onStop on SIII - I didnt got onsurfacetexturedestroyed. Its called only after onDestroy.

How I can manually destroy textureview in onStop?

Comment: This is interesting - I'm having the exact same problem on an old S2...

Comment: I encouter this on mi 2s.

Comment: @Sergey Maslenyuk did you ever find the reason for the differences?

Comment: @HadasKaminsky No. I don't remember how I fixed it on my side. But definitely with some hack.